# Python summing negative number in a array

Tags: python

Super new to programming. trying to sum up negative numbers in array. this is what i got so far.

```
def ma # define the variables needed to test the required functions
       myvals = [1, -1, 2, -3.5, 8.5]
       ArraySumNegative(myvals):
       if i<0 
      printsum(myvals)
```

Comment: What is wrong with just `sum(myvals)`?

Comment: sum(i for i in myvals if i<0)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for a function like this :

```
def sumOfNegativ(arrayOfValue):
    res = 0    
    for i in arrayOfValue:
         if i < 0:
         res += i
    return res
```

And to display the result :

```
print(sumOfNegativ(myvals))
```